# How to use more then one CLOB field on a page on ORACLE APEX 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, clob

I have a CRUD page, a form in APEX (version 5), and the corresponding table has two CLOB fields. I need to modify both fields on the same page. I´m aware of a know solution that apears to be very widespread, one that uses the collection APEX_COLLECTION and Processes that loads the CLOB field and update the modified values.

```
/** PL/SQL for loading the CLOB field */
declare
l_clob clob:= empty_clob();

begin
   if apex_collection.collection_exists(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT') then apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT');
    end if;
 apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT');
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_clob, false, dbms_lob.SESSION );

    select DS_CONCLUSAO
    into l_clob
    from CR_RELATORIO    
    where ID_RELATORIO = :P15_ID_RELATORIO; 

    apex_collection.add_member(p_collection_name => 'CLOB_CONTENT',p_clob001 => l_clob);
end;

/** Javascript Functions for loading and setting the field on the page */

<script type="text/javascript">

function clob_set(campo, operacao){  
        var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob(  
            function(){  
                var rs = p.readyState  
                if(rs == 1||rs == 2||rs == 3){  
                    $x_Show('AjaxLoading');  
                }else if(rs == 4){  
                    $s(campo,p.responseText);  
                    $x_Hide('AjaxLoading');  
                    apex.submit(operacao);
                }else{return false;}  
            }
        );  

        if (!apex.item(campo).isEmpty()) {
            clob_ob._set($v(campo));
        }
    }  

    function clob_get(campo){  
        if ($v(campo) != null && $v(campo) != '') {
          var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob(  
            function(){  
                var rs = p.readyState  
                if(rs == 1||rs == 2||rs == 3){  
                    $x_Show('AjaxLoading');  
                }else if(rs == 4){  
                    $s(campo,p.responseText);  
                    $x_Hide('AjaxLoading');  
                }else{return false;}  
            }
          );  
          clob_ob._get();  
        }
    }


</script>
```

I´m trying to use this solution, but **the problem is: that collection has only one space for a CLOB field, and i need two (or more) spaces for the two CLOB field on the DB table**.

I tried to create two different APEX_COLLECTIONS on the same page, with different names, but it´s not working.

Answer (score 1):

`APEX_COLLECTION` is just a convenient wrapper for a table with automatic purging after the session is aged out.

In your case, I'd make my own table, with SESSION_ID as part of the key, and implement my own purge process for it.

Comment: but using your solution, how can i support two or more CLOB fiels on the same page?

Comment: What is stopping you right now? Your question was about the limitation of one clob in a collection; if you create your own table, you can have several CLOBs.

Comment: i have a table, which is populated and modified by this one page. I use the collection to load/insert the two CLOB fields from/into the table. And here's the problem, since the collection supports only one CLOB field. I don't see how the creation of another table with two CLOB fields may help.

Comment: The answer is *don't use collections*. Use your own table instead. Remember, there's nothing especially magical about collections, they're a convenient wrapper for an ordinary Oracle table.